# How to add a custom template function for Pug in Koa project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, koa

I want to add custom template functions for Pug views.

For simplicity I've created a demo file with one custom function `uppercase`:

```
const Koa = require("koa")
const views = require("koa-views")

const app = new Koa()

app.use(
  views(__dirname + "/views", {
    extension: "pug",
    options: {
      helpers: {
        uppercase: str => str.toUpperCase()
      }
    }
  })
)

app.use(ctx => ctx.render("index", { name: "Name1" }))

app.listen(3000)
```

Here is a mega simple template `views/index.pug`:

`h1= uppercase(name)`

But it doesn't work, it prints such error:

```
  TypeError: /Users/max7z/projects/test/t24__test__koa-views_pug/views/index.pug:1
    > 1| h1= uppercase(name)
      2|

  uppercase is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using Koa, but I solved a similar issue recently using [Eleventy.js](https://www.11ty.dev/) with Pug. The Pug documentation is not great on this, so it took a while to figure out.

I had to make the function a global, then use the [globals](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html) property when rendering the template.

e.g.

```
global.uppercase = function(str){
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

app.use(
 views(__dirname + "/views", {
 extension: "pug",
 options: {
    globals: ["uppercase"]
   }
 })
)
```